# Rails ActiveStorage - Content-Type of S3 Object is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I use ActiveStorage for uploading object to AWS S3. 
But the Content-Type of the uploaded S3 objects is empty. 
How can I set content-type of them?

Following is what I did.

```
@brand.compiled_css.attach(io: File.open(file_path), filename: "brand.css", content_type: "text/css")
```

My Rails version is 5.2 and Ruby version is 2.6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. Rails team didn’t start setting the Content-Type on the uploaded S3 object until 6.0.
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38817